# Server for Visual Studio Code Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, cloud, vscode-extensions, vsx

I'm trying to get access to a free cloud server to store data about my users (upon receiving their consent) from my Visual Studio Code Extension.

I thought I could use Firebase, but while in attempt to create a server, I learned that it is only tailed towards iOS, android and web applications, unity projects and flutter projects.

Is there any way or platform that I can store data on about my user's in a free cloud server that can be accessed by a VS code extension?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, any update of this issue

Comment: Yup for username and password info I'm using mongoDB, and for telemetry info I'm using Azure application insights

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are requesting a Free DB for your VS Code extension, I will suggest using the free services of Azure:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-services

[image]

If the requests on your side isn't too many, I think this should be the correct way for you to store data about your users.

Above is always free service, the Azure also has some 12 months free service such as Azure storage and Azure SQL.